# SQL query to exclude rows within same table with duplicate field values

Tags: sql

I'll try to be brief.

I have a single table that I need to get data from, Contacts.

There is a Company field and they can be in either company A or company B.

All contacts in company B will have a duplicate in Company A, that can be matched by another column `LegacyID`.

What I'm trying to get is all the Company A rows that DO NOT have someone in Company B with the same `LegacyID`.

I've tried `AND LegacyID NOT IN (SELECT LegacyID FROM Contacts WHERE Company = 'B')`  as well as `AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT LegacyID FROM Contacts WHERE Company = 'B')`.

Neither of the above work because there are 260,000 Company A contacts and 96,000 Company B.  `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` worked when there were less than 50,000 rows total, but now with data migration, the query is timing out or running forever.

Thanks

Comment: You should include sample data and desried results.

Comment: Yes, I should have.  I tried but the formatting in here made it unreadable.

Comment: So I was able to solve this by using group by.

SELECT A1.* FROM tableA A1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT LegacyID, MAX(company) as MaxComp
  FROM tableA 
  GROUP BY LegacyID
 ) B1 ON B1.LegacyID = A1.LegacyID AND B1.MaxComp = A1.Company

The query runs in under 15 seconds for all 300,000 rows.

Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, `NOT EXISTS` should do what you want:

```
select c.*
from contacts c
where companyId = 'A' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from contacts c2
                  where c2.legacyId = c.legacyId and c2.companyId = 'B'
                 );
```

For performance, you want an index on `contacts(legacyId, companyId)`.

Comment: NOT EXISTS does not work because everytime it hits the NOT EXISTS, it has to go through 96,000 rows.  And because it does this 290,000 times, the performance is terrible.

Comment: @Entreprenerdz . . . That is why the answer suggests having an index.